# Error while installing pandas==0.23 on my raspberry pi 4B device with bookworm

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi, python-wheel, building

I am facing error while installing pandas==0.23 on my Raspberry Pi 4B device with Bookworm desktop version installed. What to do?

```
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/io/sas/sas.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas/sas.o -Wno-unused-function
  In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822,
                   from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                   from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                   from pandas/io/sas/sas.c:610:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     17 | #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
        |  ^~~~~~~
  pandas/io/sas/sas.c: In function â€˜__pyx_f_6pandas_2io_3sas_4_sas_rle_decompressâ€™:
  pandas/io/sas/sas.c:3745:29: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: â€˜size_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long unsigned intâ€™} and â€˜intâ€™ [-Wsign-compare]
   3745 |   __pyx_t_10 = ((__pyx_t_38 != __pyx_v_result_length) != 0);
        |                             ^~
  pandas/io/sas/sas.c: In function â€˜__pyx_f_6pandas_2io_3sas_4_sas_rdc_decompressâ€™:
  pandas/io/sas/sas.c:4587:28: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: â€˜size_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long unsigned intâ€™} and â€˜intâ€™ [-Wsign-compare]
   4587 |   __pyx_t_8 = ((__pyx_t_32 != __pyx_v_result_length) != 0);
        |                            ^~
  pandas/io/sas/sas.c:4115:65: warning: â€˜__pyx_v_ctrl_bitsâ€™ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   4115 |     __pyx_t_8 = (((__pyx_v_ctrl_bits & __pyx_v_ctrl_mask) == 0) != 0);
        |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
  pandas/io/sas/sas.c:3885:27: note: â€˜__pyx_v_ctrl_bitsâ€™ was declared here
   3885 |   __pyx_t_5numpy_uint16_t __pyx_v_ctrl_bits;
        |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas/sas.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas/_sas.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
  cythoning pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.pyx to pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.cpp
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/pi/pandas/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'pandas.io.msgpack._packer' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -Ipandas/_libs/src/msgpack -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.o -Wno-unused-function
  g++ -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
  cythoning pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.pyx to pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/pi/pandas/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'pandas.io.msgpack._unpacker' extension
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -Ipandas/_libs/src/msgpack -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.o -Wno-unused-function
  pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp: In function â€˜PyObject* __pyx_pf_6pandas_2io_7msgpack_9_unpacker_2unpackb(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, int, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t)â€™:
  pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:2624:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: â€˜size_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long unsigned intâ€™} and â€˜Py_ssize_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long intâ€™} [-Wsign-compare]
   2624 |     __pyx_t_2 = ((__pyx_v_off < __pyx_v_buf_len) != 0);
        |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp: In function â€˜PyObject* __pyx_f_6pandas_2io_7msgpack_9_unpacker_8Unpacker_read_from_file(__pyx_obj_6pandas_2io_7msgpack_9_unpacker_Unpacker*)â€™:
  pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:4698:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: â€˜size_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long unsigned intâ€™} and â€˜Py_ssize_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long intâ€™} [-Wsign-compare]
   4698 |   if (((__pyx_t_2 < __pyx_t_3) != 0)) {
        |         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
  pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp: In function â€˜PyObject* __pyx_pf_6pandas_2io_7msgpack_9_unpacker_8Unpacker_8read_bytes(__pyx_obj_6pandas_2io_7msgpack_9_unpacker_Unpacker*, Py_ssize_t)â€™:
  pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:5329:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: â€˜Py_ssize_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long intâ€™} and â€˜size_tâ€™ {aka â€˜long unsigned intâ€™} [-Wsign-compare]
   5329 |   if (((__pyx_t_1 < __pyx_t_2) != 0)) {
        |         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
  g++ -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
  building 'pandas._libs.json' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/python -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib -Ipandas/_libs/src/datetime -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/ujson.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/ujson.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-function
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/python -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib -Ipandas/_libs/src/datetime -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-function
  In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822,
                   from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                   from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                   from pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:44:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     17 | #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
        |  ^~~~~~~
  pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c: In function â€˜initObjToJSONâ€™:
  pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:193:12: error: â€˜NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVALâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
    193 |     return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL;
        |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:193:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:194:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    194 | }
        | ^
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
Installing collected packages: pandas
    Running setup.py install for pandas ...
```

This is the error I am facing. I am sticking to pandas 0.23 because of my project dependencies.

I tried installing pandas with pip, pip3, pip3.6, cloning from git, with the help of source zip, still couldn't build it.

I am attaching the error file below as Stack Overflow is limiting the characters. [Link to complete error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AgkaUckNMaf4FPd-uLBpMo1eUdWgULed/view?usp=sharing)

here are the packages that are installed already:

```
certifi==2020.6.20
cycler==0.11.0
enum34==1.1.10
importlib-resources==5.4.0
joblib== 1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.19.5
pandas-ml==0.6.1
Pillow==8.4.0
pip==21.2.2
pyparsing==3.0.8
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1`
scikit-learn==0.21.1
scipy==1.5.4
setuptools==58.0.4
six==1.16.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tqdm==4.64.1
wheel==0.37.1
zipp==3.6.0
```

I initially tried setting up the same environment in windows system as well as in a virtual box with ubuntu. In this both cases pandas got installed without any issue. What can be the reason for not getting installed in raspberry pi?

Comment: The error suggests compatibility problems with NumPy, but you haven't divulged which version of NumPy you are compiling against.

Comment: iam using numpy==1.19.5

Comment: At the time Pandas 0.23.4 was released (August 2018) the current version of NumPy was [1.14.5](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.14.5/), have you tried that? You are unlikely who is willing and able to find anyone who is willing and able to support such an old prerelease version of Pandas so you are putting in yourself for a world of hurt by not upgrading.

Comment: thank you sooo much it really means a lot it's working after downgrading numpy to 1.14.5